# ArcMap 10.2 Shapefile Labels Don't Work With Pigiarniq Font

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I've recently asked the question to the ESRI help team and apparently it's an unreported bug. I've also had a few suggestions from some people on GeoNet but none have worked. So here it goes:

The problem I am having is that my "XY Event Source" labels do not work when I convert them to shapefiles.

When I click "Label Features", my points in the shapefiles display a bunch of question marks (?).

I am using the Pigiarniq font which I have downloaded on my computer.

Even when I change the "Text Symbol" from the "Layer Properties" to Pigiarniq font instead of standard Arial, it comes up as question marks (?).

Comment: What language is the text? English? Japanese? Does it display properly with a more standard font? And what is the datasource for your XY event layer? Excel? CSV? DBF?

Comment: Pigiarniq is Canadian (Inuktitut) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuktitut#The_Canadian_syllabary

Comment: This is a bug in ArcGIS 10.2 seems to be fixed in 10.3 (can you upgrade to 10.3?)

Comment: I'll have to ask my supervisor about it

Comment: to MWreen, the files I am using are microsft excel. I have tried to save them as CSV and DBF files but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: If this is a known bug in 10.2, and if upgrading is out, is converting the excel file to a shapefile in QGIS or maybe using Arcpy/python an option for you?

Comment: I'm not very savvy past the basics so maybe?

Comment: I guess it depends on this mysterious bug. I can't find it documented anywhere. Is is just that the XY Event source process can't handle this particular encoding, or is it that regardless of data source, ArcGIS can't display these characters?

Comment: @JulienFavreau Potentially it is to do with keyboard mappings try loading http://www.publiclibraries.nu.ca/prog_ik.html

Comment: @MWrenn The font works when it is only an XY event source, but once I export it to become a shapefile, the font shows up as question marks. The reason I want to export my data into shapefiles is because it is the only way that I can then do "select by location" queries.

Comment: @Mapperz I just tried using the Inuktitut keyboard and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Since Arc 10.2 doesn't like your font/encoding, QGIS may be able to help get this data into a shapefile format. It has a very similar process to what you are working with already in Arc. I have no idea if it will work better for you, or if it will have the exact same issues.

See http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html for a process to convert a CSV into a shapefile. You will first obviously need to correctly convert your excel file into a csv. Once you've got the shapefile, you can hopefully continue your workflow in ArcGIS.